# Power BI How to Convert from Checkboxes to Slider

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have 2 date columns. Both are of the Date data type.
One of them is a slider, the other a checkbox.

How do I convert from checkbox to slider?

Answer (score 0):

your question is little confusing, however to change checkbox to slider you need:

1. go to the modelling tab and change you **datetime value** to something like below:
   [image]
2. in slicer visual go to part **select type of your slicer** and choose **between**
   [image]